# Flip image in svg centered at x,y

Tags: javascript, svg, href, flip

I am trying to invert an image in svg. I came across this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406997/flip-all-embedded-images-in-a-svg-file/19407196?noredirect=1#comment71328056_19407196) but this solution works for images placed at the origin (0,0).

If the width of the image is 100 and the image is at (0,0), then I do the following

```
img.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'translate(100,0) scale(-1,1)');
```

I tried to flip/invert an image placed at (x,y) but the image disappears. I am not clear as to what translation I should use.

The fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dm89/7b25vq82/2/)
If you uncomment the lines to set the attributes (x,y) for the image, the image disappears.

I want to understand how the scale function exactly works and what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

On Request from @blex and with modification he proposed... Here is the solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/7b25vq82/5/

You need to calculate the flip location and once your make the calculations, initial code you have in the Q works fine...

```
var img = document.getElementById("flip");
var xCord = 100;
var yCord = 100;
var imageSize = 100;
var flipLocation = (xCord*2 + imageSize);

img.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', xCord);
img.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', yCord);

img.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'translate('+flipLocation+',0) scale(-1,1)');
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty visual explanation: http://imgur.com/a/CVDwo

Comment: @blex so cool... That visual is outstanding.